# Get URL and remove first image in an HTML String with Java

Tags: java, html, image, url

I want to get the URL of the first image in an HTML String and then replace it with an empty String.

The images can be in this two forms in my String:

```
<img src="http://www.mywebsite.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/picture.jpg" alt="MyImage" width="635" height="311" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-32729" />

<img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-38590" src="http://www.mywebsite.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/picture2.jpg" alt="MyImage2" width="635" height="303" />
```

I want to extract the URL as String `http://www.mywebsite.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/picture.jpg` and replace it with an empty string.

At the moment I use this code to get the URL:

```
/**
 * Method to get the URL of the first image
 */

public String getFirstImageURL(String description){

Document doc = Jsoup.parse(description);
Element imageElement = doc.select("img").first();
String absoluteUrl = imageElement.absUrl("src");  //absolute URL on src
//String srcValue = imageElement.attr("src");  // exact content value of the attribute.
return absoluteUrl;
}
```

This way I can retrieve the correct URL but I cannot replace the complete HTML tag with an emptry String. If I use

```
    // Get description string
    String imageURL = getFirstImageURL(HTMLString);
    HTMLString = HTMLString.replaceAll(imageURL, "");
```

I still have `<img src="" alt="MyImage" width="635" height="317" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-13794" />` in the HTMLString.

Anyone an idea how I can completely replace the HTML tag?

**SOLUTION**

/**
 * Method to get the URL of the first image
 */
public String getFirstImageURL(String description){

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(description);
Element imageElement = doc.select("img").first();
imageURL = imageElement.absUrl("src");  //absolute URL on src
imageElement.remove();
description = doc.toString();
return description;
```

}

Comment: You can use http://jsoup.org/ for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i understand, you want to remove the entire

```
Element imageElement = doc.select("img").first();
imageElement.remove();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but the tag in the HTMLString is still: <img src="http://www.mywebsite.de/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/image.jpg" alt="Image" width="635" height="317" class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-13794" />. So the tag is not removed, any idea why?

Comment: I solved the problem and added the solution to the first post. Thanks for your help!